# Calling controller methods

Tags: php, laravel

Hi I am new to the laravel framework and I seem to be having some trouble in calling specific methods from controllers.

Here is what I have done so far.

I have configured the route to the controller:

```
Route::controller('users', 'UserController');

class UserController extends BaseController{

public $restful = true;

public function get_index($id = null) 
{
    $ceva = new Model();
    return Response::json($ceva );
}

public function get_index2() 
{
    return "something";
}
```

}

Comming from a background of ASP.NET MVC I expected to call each method like this:

```
http://localhost:8585/RestPHP/public/users/get_index
http://localhost:8585/RestPHP/public/users/get_index
```

But this throws a controller method not found exception.

It seems do that in knows how to get the get_index method by itself.

If I call :

> `http://localhost:8585/RestPHP/public/users/`

I get my json repsonse

How can I call each method as I need?

Comment: I can recommend you to watch this lesson about restful controllers in Laravel 3 - [Restful Controllers](https://tutsplus.com/lesson/restful-controllers/) by @JeffreyWay

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're working in Laravel 3 or 4?

The method name defines the verb + URI. So, for `get_index`, the url would simply be `/index`...not `/get_index`.

If using v4, you might consider using resourceful controllers instead.